# Using _splitpath function in Android NDK

Tags: c, android-ndk

In Android NDK, is their a way to use _splitpath function which available in C stdlib.h?

I have include

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and when I call the function

```
char fname[_MAX_FNAME];
char extn[_MAX_FNAME];
_splitpath(filename.c_str(), NULL, NULL, fname, extn);
```

It give out error that it cannot find _MAX_FNAME. So I do a quick hack by declare it manually. But then it can not find _splitpath function still. The exact error is

: undefined reference to '_splitpath'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_splitpath()` and `_MAX_FNAME` are part of MSVC's runtime - they aren't standard, and are not part of GCC's library or a Linux system call.

You might be able to do what you want using `dirname()` and `basename()`.